# Highlight imageview of a tablerow

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout with three rows into it. my xml file is like

```
<TableLayout>
<TableRow>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
    <ImageView/>
</TableRow>.
```

Now what i want is by pressing button i want to highlight the imageviews one by one. Can u please help in achieving this. Thanks in advance.

Note: I need to highlight the image on button touch and when pressed i need to navigate from one activity to another.

Comment: do you want a persistent highlight or just a feedback to the touch event?

Comment: i want a persistent highlight so that the user can understand that the view is clicked.

Comment: so you can change the background of the imageview when is clicked, and restore all the backgrounds when the activity is resumed. could you post the code of your onClickListners?

Comment: I don't have any idea over onclick. can u give an example for this.

Comment: ok i can post some code, the point is: in activity A you have several ImageView, when click on one of the ImageView activity B is started. If activity B is started, activity A will be no longer visible so what's the point in having ImageView highlighted? when going back to activity A, ImageView wouldn't be highlighted anymore, right?

Comment: yes you are right. the same i need for all images.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38604/discussion-between-all-is-well-and-lelloman)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this, to make the ImageView react to a click you have to call setOnClickListener on your ImageView, e.g.

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);

iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // do your stuff
    }
});
```

You could also let your activity implement OnClickListener and call

```
iv.setOnClickListener(this);
```

so that on imageview clicked will be call the method on the activity.

to make it react to click, you could change the background color of the imageview  inside onClick OR you could just use a selector and set it as background for your ImageView inside the xml e.g.

selector.xml (inside drawable folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_image_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_image_pressed"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_image_unpressed" />
</selector>
```

and inside your xml layout

```
<ImageView
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for ur response..I tried with selector already. without this highlight can not be possible ah?